# Dell R610 ESXi not loading after VD deleted

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi, dell

I've got an R610 which had 3x RAID 1 arrays in it previously, with one degraded and inaccessible (has been for months). After rebooting, I was warned that VD00 was missing. Given I didn't care about the data on this degraded array, I deleted the preserved cache and continued to boot normally.

This allowed me into the ESXi loading screen, however it has now been sitting on "ntfs41 client loaded successfully" for 3 hours. Whilst there was an NFS share on the ESXi configuration that is no longer accessible (see attached image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eEHN.jpg)), I suspect the issue is that the original VD is missing  which has muddled up the drive order ESXi is attempting to use.

How can I fix this ordering?

[image: Alt + F12 output]

Comment: Did you try a simple reinstallation of ESXi?

Comment: @Barnabus Busa. This is an interesting thought. I assume I need the same major/minor version of ESXi? If I reinstall (or install to a new OS drive - easy enough as it runs off a USB), I can simply load my datastores and VMs? Would I lose anything besides metadata, logs and auth data? Do you have a link to a resource? Thank you!

Comment: Assuming that you are loading up a newer (or same version) of the esxi, all the datastores and VMs should be accessible. I have just done this the other day. Make sure you upgrade to a version that is still officially supported though, otherwise you might encounter compatibility issues.

Comment: @BarnabasBusa just letting you know this worked perfectly. In fact due to a series of silly choices I ended up having to do this twice. Please feel free to write this up as an answer and I'll mark it as such, otherwise I'll add it myself in a few days. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are loading up a newer (or same version) of the esxi, all the datastores and VMs should be accessible. I have just done this the other day. Make sure you upgrade to a version that is still officially supported though, otherwise you might encounter compatibility issues.